Spring cloud stream multi cluster connection: AdminClient and Consumer throw error: Failed to create consumer binding
Problem: when I try to configure multi cluster connection for spring cloud stream kafka my application throw an error for each topic: Failed to create consumer binding retrying in 30 seconds org.springframework.cloud.stream.provisioning.ProvisioningException: Provisioning exception encountered for topic
Versions: Spring Boot 3.1.9 Spring Cloud 2022.0.5
application configuration file based on official github:
spring:
  application.name: ${application.name}
  main.banner-mode: off
  cloud:
    function:
      definition: someFunctionalConsumer
    stream:
      default-binder: kafka1
      bindings:
        someFunctionalConsumer-in-0:
          destination: ${application.kafka.consumer.sourceTopicName},${application.kafka.consumer.retryTopicName}
          binder: kafka1
          group: ${CONSUMER_GROUP}
          content-type: application/*+avro
          consumer:
            concurrency: ${LISTENER_CONCURRENCY:1}
        stream-bridge-out:
          destination: ${application.kafka.producer.destinationTopicName}
          content-type: application/*+avro
          binder: kafka2
          producer:
            useNativeEncoding: true
      function:
        definition: someFunctionalConsumer
      binders:
        kafka1:
          type: kafka
          default-candidate: true
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: ${application.kafka.bootstrap-servers.consumer}
                      configuration:
                        bearer.auth.credentials.source: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.credentials.source}
                        bearer.auth.logical.cluster: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.logical.cluster}
                        bearer.auth.identity.pool.id: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.identity.pool.id}
                        security.protocol: ${application.kafka.security.protocol}
                        sasl:
                          # spring said that in consumer config this property does not use
                          oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url: ${OAUTHBEARER_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL}
                          jaas.config: ${application.kafka.auth.jaas.config}
                          mechanism: ${application.kafka.auth.mechanism}
                          login.callback.handler.class: ${application.kafka.auth.login.callback.handler.class}
        kafka2:
          type: kafka
          default-candidate: false
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                stream:
                  kafka:
                    binder:
                      brokers: ${application.kafka.bootstrap-servers.producer}
                      configuration:
                        bearer.auth.credentials.source: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.credentials.source}
                        bearer.auth.logical.cluster: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.logical.cluster}
                        bearer.auth.identity.pool.id: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.identity.pool.id}
                        security.protocol: ${application.kafka.security.protocol}
                        sasl:
                          oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url: ${OAUTHBEARER_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL}
                          jaas.config: ${application.kafka.auth.jaas.config}
                          mechanism: ${application.kafka.auth.mechanism}
                          login.callback.handler.class: ${application.kafka.auth.login.callback.handler.class}
      kafka:
        bindings:
          someFunctionalConsumer-in-0:
            consumer:
              startOffset: ${START_OFFSET_POLICY:earliest}
              ack-mode: RECORD
              configuration:
                session.timeout.ms: 35000
                max.poll.records: ${MAX_POLL_RECORDS:1}
                auto.register.schemas: false
                specific.avro.reader: true
                key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: com.common.dlq.client.serializer.RawDataDeserializerProxy
                dlq.client.deserializer.key.delegate.class: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
                value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: com.common.dlq.client.serializer.RawDataDeserializerProxy
                dlq.client.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.value.function: com.nordstrom.orbit.fp.router.stream.FailedDeserializationFunction
                schema.registry.url: ${application.kafka.schema-registry.schema.registry.url}
                bearer.auth.credentials.source: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.credentials.source}
                bearer.auth.logical.cluster: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.logical.cluster}
                bearer.auth.identity.pool.id: ${application.kafka.auth.bearer.auth.identity.pool.id}
                security.protocol: ${application.kafka.security.protocol}
          stream-bridge-out:
            producer:
              sync: true
              recordMetadataChannel: meta
              configuration:
                delivery.timeout.ms: 300000
                acks: all
                retries: 5
                enable.idempotence: true
                auto.register.schemas: false
                avro.remove.java.properties: true
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
                value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
                value.subject.name.strategy: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.RecordNameStrategy
                useNativeEncoding: true
                schema.registry.url: ${application.kafka.schema-registry.schema.registry.url}

admin client and consumer fallback to default configuration and are not considering at all to the stuff that I provided:
AdminClientConfig values:
        auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 300000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 2147483647
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS

Consumer:
ConsumerConfig values:
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = consumer-null-1
        client.rack =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = true
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = null
        group.instance.id = null
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 45000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer

I debug different spring cloud configuration beans:
KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties is filled with default values
BindingServiceProperties filled with information but does not taken into account
created debug method where I load BinderFactory:
void debugChannels() {
    final Binder<MessageChannel, ?, ?> binder1 =
        binderFactory.getBinder("kafka1", MessageChannel.class);
    final KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafka1 = (KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binder1;
    final DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor1 = new DirectFieldAccessor(kafka1);
    final KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configuration1 =
        (KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties)
            directFieldAccessor1.getPropertyValue("configurationProperties");

    log.debug("kafka consumer broker: {}", Arrays.toString(configuration1.getBrokers()));

    final Binder<MessageChannel, ?, ?> binder2 =
        binderFactory.getBinder("kafka2", MessageChannel.class);
    final KafkaMessageChannelBinder kafka2 = (KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binder2;
    final DirectFieldAccessor directFieldAccessor2 = new DirectFieldAccessor(kafka2);
    final KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties configuration2 =
        (KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties)
            directFieldAccessor2.getPropertyValue("configurationProperties");

    log.debug("kafka producer broker: {}", Arrays.toString(configuration2.getBrokers()));
  }

both return:

kafka producer broker: [localhost]


I suggest creating a very minimal version of your setup (maybe try to remove all those complex security configs altogether) and see if you can identify where the issue occurs. See this (and others in the same folder) working sample to compare: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas/src/main/resources/application.yml

removed all configuration blocks problem still the same.
BinderProperties is filled, MessageChannels and merged configuration with default values

at localhost all works well, it can somehow bind to the any range from 9090-9099 with embedded kafka, with external kafka in docker or in k8s does not work

that how BindingSericeProperties filled without authentication:
environment binder kafka1: {spring={cloud={stream={kafka={binder={brokers=bla.nonprod.domain.sub.net:9093}}}}}}
and KafkaBinderConfigurationProperties
connection merged consumer props: {key.deserializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer, bootstrap.servers=[localhost:9092], value.deserializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer, isolation.level=read_uncommitted}

and want to mention, I ma using construction for consumer like this:
@Compoment("someFunctionalConsumer")
class SomeFunctionalConsumer implement Consumer<Message<SpecificRecordBase>>


The root cause:
@Import(KafkaBinderConfiguration.class) in the custom kafka health check bean (I don't know why importing spring cloud configuration break gathering properties)
But now I have another problem : Spring cloud cannot create bindings for streamBridge and my custom error handler is broken (spring do not set option into container)
@Bean
  ListenerContainerCustomizer<AbstractMessageListenerContainer<byte[], byte[]>> customizer(
      final StreamErrorHandler errorHandler) {
    return (container, dest, group) -> {
      container.setCommonErrorHandler(errorHandler);
      final ContainerProperties properties = container.getContainerProperties();
      properties.setAckMode(AckMode.RECORD);
    };
  }


Could you please create a minimal application with a README to reproduce the issue? Then we can triage the issue further. Thanks!
